# C++ - Forward declaration and alias (with using or typedef)

Tags: c++, templates, alias, using, forward-declaration

I need to implement the following interface

```
struct mutex;
struct interface
{
  //...
  mutex& getMutex();
};
```

Intuition would I could use `using mutex = ParticularMutex` in my implementation, but gcc tells me otherwise:

```
error: conflicting declaration ‘using mutex = ’
error: ‘class mutex’ has a previous declaration as ‘class mutex’
```

I am not *defining* anything twice, only *declaring* twice, as usual when forward declaring, so

1. why doesn't this work?
2. is there a workaround without modifying `interface`?
3. how should `interface` have been defined? with `template <typename mutex>`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. It does not work because the forward declaration `struct mutex;` tells the compiler that `mutex` is a new type. With `using` you are then creating a type **alias**, which means it's not a *new* type (as promised to the compiler), but an alias to an existing type.
2. No.
3. Yes.

---

What you *could* do is:

```
struct mutex : ParticularMutex {
    using ParticularMutex::ParticularMutex; // inherit constructors
};
```

Which does define a type derived from `ParticularMutex` which is hopefully compatible enough. Of course, this is a new type which might lead to other problems.

Comment: Still, I don't see why the compiler should care. I wonder why there isn't a way to forward declare that says "this name represents _some_ type. You don't need to know the exact definition for now but you will have it at link-time"

Comment: @ricab The compiler cares because this is what the standard requires. Whether or not it is useful or if there *should* be some way to forward-declare a type-alias is a different question. And quite frankly, a template parameter is exactly that: It tells `interface` that you will provide some type (or type-alias) later on.

Comment: @ricab I updated the answer with a possible solution, check if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering what is the reasoning for the standard not to include a more general fwd declaration mechanism. I see no relevant change in semantics when defining `mutex` with a typedef

Comment: Also, your solution works. You would have to modify your answer to 2. from "No" to "Yes" :) BTW, it's worth noting that _using_ the constructors that way is not supported by gcc4.7 (I had to use an online compiler to confirm it)

Comment: @ricab I'll leave 2) as I think this is not a work-around for the underlying problem, it's just how you define `mutex`. Anyways, I'm glad it helped in your case (although, yes, constructor inheritance is a C++11 thing and not implemented in older compiler versions).

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation (working with JNI abstraction), here is what I do:

JNI-unaware file **MyObject.h**:

```
class PlatformObject; // forward declaration
struct MyObject {
        int accumulator;
        PlatformObject* platformObj;
};
```

JNI-aware file **jniBridge.cpp**:

```
#include <jni.h>
#define PlatformObject _jobject
#include "MyObject.h"

void attach(MyObject& obj, jobject parent) {
    obj.platformObj = env->GetObjectField(parent, child_FieldID);
}

void add(MyObject& obj, int k) {
    accumulator += k;
    env->CallVoidMethod(obj.platformObj, add_MethodID, k);
}
```

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834645/c-forward-declaration-and-alias-with-using-or-typedef#18834727) works for **add()** but not for **attach()**; extra **static_cast** is required for the latter.

I believe that in some cases, both approaches have their advantages.

Answer (score 0):

- First you're saying that `mutex` is a specific class type. Then later you're saying "oh wait, `mutex` isn't its own type, it's really *this other type* instead". The compiler doesn't know what to do in that case.
- Replace `struct mutext` with the using and it should just work (I'm not totally up to date on C++11 using).
- If you want to be able to support multiple mutex implementations, you might want to make the interface a template (or use a mutex abstract interface that virtually decides which mutex implementation to call).

Comment: Thanks, regarding 2: I was perhaps not explicit enough, but I meant "is there a workaround without modifying the _file_ where `interface` _and_ the forward declaration are in?"

Answer (score 0):

Well, you usually can solve this problem by adding a stub declaration of that `ParticularMutex` to one of your headers. Something like:

```
namespace foreignlib {
    namespace foreignsublib {
        class ParticularMutex;
    }
}
```

And then in your general header:

```
namespace ourlib {
    using mutex = foreignlib::foreignsublib::ParticularMutex;
}
```

This works fine and parses and compiles fast. The advantage: Whoever reads your general header knows, what this your specific `mutex` stands for after all. The disadvantage: You cannot write a mutex-agnostic library, where later you can drop in one or the other mutex using the `using` directive. If you want or need to do that, the C++ Gods want you to use templates instead. But these come at their own price...